# Multiple wordpress installations using same database - can they share plugin settings?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have multiple Wordpress installations sharing a database. I have been asked specifically not to use Multisite. The installs are also sharing the same wp-content folder. Is it possible for the sites to also share the same plugin options? I found a method for sharing the same user table across the sites - but I don't need that functionality. I just need the ability to globally set plugin options across all sites.

If this is not possible or not practical, since the sites would have different urls etc, I could work around it if I could essentially take a snapshot of the plugin settings of a master installation and stick those settings into the database at installation of a new install.

What I'm building is a Wordpress install launcher, which launches brand new wordpress installations that contain a predefined set of themes, plugins, pages and settings. I've worked most of it out. Currently I can fill out a form which then unzips the customized base wordpress package and installs it, creating the page content, activating the custom theme and the plugins. So I'm at a point now where the last thing I need to build into this functionality is to set a boatload of options during the install. As an example, one option I'd like to be able to set is a standard default logo for each install. Another example is that I'd like to automatically set the google maps api key for the theme that I'm using. I hope you get the idea.

I found this helpful page in the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

So at this point I think that what I need to do is to retrieve the various options/settings that I need from the base wordpress that forms the image that all new installs should mirror, and then use code like this:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table_name, 
    array( 
        'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 
        'name' => $welcome_name, 
        'text' => $welcome_text, 
    ) 
);
```

and the other associated code from the above codex link to insert all of that data into the new Wordpress install during the install process.

**I think what I'm looking for with my question is this:** Does this seem like the correct and most efficient way to do this? And secondarily: the job of retrieving all of the settings for all of the existing plugins in my base install feels like a laborious chore. Any suggestions on a method for quickly identifying and retrieving the option/setting information for a particular plugin?

Comment: I read it, but you should use a Multisite. That's the standard of WP. If you use your way, you have a lot of custom doings, also you should maintain this. On each update you have a lot of topics. If you use Multisite way, you have the way to change the standard via Hook in the Multisite, much easier - I think.

Comment: For whatever reason, the client has explicitly asked me not to use multiste. Therefore, multisite is not an option.

Comment: I think you would have to use some kind of foreach() loop in order to be able to cross populate settings straight to the db. for example, if plugin 1 has settings, for each site, add settings to db. I think thats what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the sites to also share the same plugin options?

No.

> Does this seem like the correct and most efficient way to do this?

No, certainly not. It puts you in the role of developer for every single plugin you use. That's completely unreasonable.

> The installs are also sharing the same wp-content folder.

If this works, it will be a miracle. Parts of WordPress assign filenames to files in that folder based on stuff in their own database tables. How can you possibly prevent collisions?

> I have been asked specifically not to use Multisite.

Refuse this request. *Run, don't walk,* away from the fool making this totally unreasonable demand. Or spend the next years of your life messing around with a FrankenPress installation that will *always* be fragile. The only good that can come from it?  You'll have a fun submission to http://thedailywtf.com/ so the rest of us can shake our heads sadly.

Let me offer you some arguments you may be able to use against this approach.

WordPress is a long-lived code base. It has many core developers, and thousands upon thousands of plugin developers. Over the years, it has established a set of standards for how its various components cooperate. Some, but by no means all, those standards are formalized. Plugin and theme developers are allowed to do pretty much anything they want that doesn't violate the formalized standards, and doesn't break WordPress. Actually, they are allowed to break WordPress. If they do, their plugins and themes get low ratings.  It's a vast software ecosystem, one of the largest. And it pretty much works.

The creators of WordPress have put together single-site and multi-site installation schemes. These schemes have been tested at scale all over the place, not incidentally at WordPress.com.   They pretty much work.

But, there's a steady stream of updates for plugins, themes, and the WordPress core. These updates address security problems and add functionality. The "pretty much anything they want" rule applies to updates as well as new items. So, if you think you know how a particular plugin works today, and the author updates it, you don't know how it works tomorrow. Or, maybe you know how it works tomorrow, but you'll have to inspect the code or test it.

The WordPress team built Multisite to handle what your employer seems to want. Your employer seems to have persuaded you to build another version of Multisite. Unless your name happens to be [Matt Mullenweg](https://ma.tt/), with respect you probably don't have enough time left in your life to get this right. Even if you're fifteen.

The consequences of getting it wrong will be grievous. Site security and stability will suffer. Plugin updates will break. Some themes will work, and others won't. Some site visitors will see content belonging to sites other than the one they visited.

Your boss can say, "I want to go by railroad to New York City. But I don't want to take the train. Here's a torch: weld some steel wheels onto my car. By the way, you're coming with me."   What are you going to say?  You can talk about railroad signaling, about safety, about switches, about how fast various trains go, and how complex things are at Grand Central Terminal, and all that.  And, you can say, "no." Say all the stuff if you want. But please say "no."

There are plugins that do a good job of cloning WordPress installations quickly to stand up new installations. They preserve plugin settings.

Comment: I was not aware that wordpress changes files in the wp-content folder can you give an example of that?

Comment: I'm not sure that copying settings from a plugin in one wordpress installation and using them in a different wordpress installation puts me in any plugin developer role - many plugins offer this functionality (advanced custom fields, Yoast SEO.)

Comment: `wp-content` contains `uploads` (images, files etc.), `plugins` (all the plugins), `mu-plugins` (must use plugins, intended for multisite use), `upgrade`, `themes` and `languages`. Any time you upload a plugin, or an image, or change theme those files are affected. So yes, WordPress  definitely changes files in the `wp-content` folder.

I get the feeling like you don't want to abandon the ludicrous task your client has set for you, even though O. Jones has given you great arguments and advice as to why not to go with it...

Comment: Yes I understand those things - but we do want all of the different wordpress installations to have matching upload folders, theme folders, pulgins folders etc. The folks who manage the individual wordpress installs will not have access to the dashboard, so only the two admins of the overall system will be uploading files etc. But I believe I'd be right to assume that theme and plugin files don't get changed by wordpress in a way that would cause them not to work in a site that's sharing the plugin. And no, I did not ask the question so that I could say no to the work. I intend to do the work.